# ggplot2 : Error in barplot - X axis displayed improperly

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data which shows total sales in the years 2013 and 2014.

```
yr_sales
    Year    sum_amount
1   2013    277125.0
2   2014    331721.8
```

I wish to draw a barplot with Year on X and sales on Y axis.

```
ggplot(yr_sales, aes(x=Year, y=sum_amount)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="lightblue", colour="black")
```

But all I get is a messed up X axis :
[image: Bar Plot 1]

My expected output is (as I got in MS Excel)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your year is treated as a numerical variable. The way you want to display your data requires it to be a factor (i.e., it has discrete values and there cannot be a year `2013.5`).

Set `as.factor(Year)` for the aesthetic mapping of your x axis:

```
ggplot(yr_sales, aes(x=as.factor(Year), y=sum_amount)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="lightblue", colour="black")
```

[image]

You could also change the data itself, but this could cause issues when you want your year as an actual numerical variable:

```
yr_sales$Year = as.factor(yr_sales$Year)
```

If you did the above, you would not need to use `as.factor` in the aesthetic mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer given by @slhck I did the below thing :

```
ggplot(yr_sales, aes(x=as.factor(Year), y=sum_amount,width=0.4)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="blue", colour="black")
```

And my output is perfect..

[image]